# Is this wording correct ? Using "howmany" for countable quantity instead of however in this phrase

Tags: word-choice

Can I have "Show Step 1 of howmany more there are" Similarly to having "Do this regardless of however long it takes" To convey the meaning: "Show Step 1 of N Steps, where N is different for different cases"

I'm looking for the word carrying the same meaning as "however" in the second sentence, but for countable quantity.

Note: English is not my first language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Howmany isn't a valid English word; the correct way to say it would be "however many". So for example

> Do this however many steps there are.

Comment: It should be though, saves some time and is just as meaningful. Thanks
"Show Step 1 of however many steps there are"

Comment: That works, yes. I think the issue with this being a thing is that "howmany" and "how many" would mean different things and would end up being mistaken for each other more often than not.